# manpath: can't set the locale; make sure $LC_* and $LANG are correct

Tags: locale

I just installed terminator terminal emulator on my linux mint. for some reason I don't understand, it sets my password to some of the locale options. I've tried several things but they only offer a temporary fix. each time I open the terminal, it resets the locale options to my password.

```
LANG=koldenod19*
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="mypassword"
LC_NUMERIC=om_KE.UTF-8
LC_TIME="mypassword"
LC_COLLATE="mypassword"
LC_MONETARY=om_KE.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="mypassword"
LC_PAPER=om_KE.UTF-8
LC_NAME=om_KE.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=om_KE.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=om_KE.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=om_KE.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=om_KE.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

I've tried using `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales` and `export LC_ALL="eo_US.utf8"` and the problem still persists.

Comment: This worked for me: [enter link description here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/431963/557287)

Answer (score 139):

Try this https://gist.github.com/SimonSun1988/2ef7db45e46b889783647d941ec15e4d

```
sudo locale-gen "en_US.UTF-8"
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

and in file `/etc/default/locale` add line `LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"` and relogin to your server.

Comment: WHat's the name of the YUM package ? (running Amazon-linux 2, cannot find `locale-gen`)

Comment: @CyrilDuchon-Doris try just add line LC_ALL... maybe it will work for you without any extra commands

Comment: This works, though I still don't know what caused this issue in the first place, probably due to some encoding package that I installed or an upgrade to python ?

Comment: Something seems to be implied, but hasn't actually been confirmed... Do all the locale variables need to use an `en_US` or `en_GB` locale for these errors to go away? My `LC_*` variables are a mix of `en_US` and `ms_MY`, which _is_ correct for me (American living in Malaysia), but I'm getting the same error.

Comment: @Vince just LC_ALL should be in locale file

Answer (score 53):

For *CentOS* this worked for me.

Add these lines to `/etc/environment`

```
LANG=en_US.utf-8
LC_ALL=en_US.utf-8
```

Comment: This worked for me on AWS Amazon Linux AMI

Comment: Also on Debian Wheezy/Jessie

Comment: It works also on Ubuntu 20.04 Focal Fossa

Comment: Also worked  for my Manjaro system.

Comment: Worked for me on debian 10

Comment: Worked on Arch Linux

Comment: Worked for me on Debian 11

Answer (score 11):

Edit your `/etc/locale.gen` then uncomment the following line:

```
en_GB.UTF-8 UTF-8
```

Run:

```
sudo locale-gen en_GB.UTF-8 UTF-8
sudo update-locale en_GB.UTF-8 UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en_GB.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_GB.UTF-8
```

Verify it;

```
locale
```

You may get:

```
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_GB.UTF-8
```

And Done !!!

Answer (score 3):

If you encounter this issue and are working based on Docker.

Install locales first and then generate locale.

```
apt install locales
locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are having this problem on CentOS, follow this example because nothing else worked for me.

The command `localedef -i en_US -f UTF-8 en_US.UTF-8` fixes the problem, but may lead to another one:

```
[error] character map file UTF-8' not found: No such file or directory
default character map file ANSI_X3.4-1968' not found: No such file or directory.
```

Finally, executing `yum -y install glibc-locale-source` prior to `localedef -i en_US -f UTF-8 en_US.UTF-8` installs the missing files and changes back the locale.

Now locale reports again:

```
LANG=en_US

.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
(...)
LC_ALL=
```

Hope that helps someone out there.

Comment: work for me on centos.

Answer (score 1):

RedHat: Change /etc/locale.conf to

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ALL=en_US.utf-8
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me :

```
echo "LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8" >> /etc/environment
echo "en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8" >> /etc/locale.gen
echo "LANG=en_US.UTF-8" > /etc/locale.conf
locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
```

[Source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/431963/557287)

Answer (score 0):

**This answer is only relevant to KDE / Plasma**:

Assuming that you still have these issues after the solutions shown in the top answers, you could look for a file located at `~/.config/plasma-localerc`.

Plasma does store Locale Configurations here — but they would be better of in `/etc/locale.conf`.

Anyhow, after doing the rename / delete and doing a reboot, the error should no longer be present. You can run `locale` to get the detailed locale setup.
Modify the `/etc/locale.conf` file as needed.

Solution Reference: https://forum.manjaro.org/t/manpath-cant-set-locale/20099/8